# ggplot2: How do I set the default fill-colour of geom_bar() in a theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to define a theme for ggplot2 so that the default colour of geom_bar() is not black.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can't do it in a theme (sadly).

You want to change the default settings of a geom,

```
  update_geom_defaults("bar",   list(fill = "red"))
```

and you can also change a default scale, e.g.

```
  scale_colour_continuous <- function(...) 
         scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", na.value="grey50", ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you mentioned that's not exactly what I was looking for but better than to specify the color in each geom_bar.

Answer (score 1):

Theme controls apperance of *non-data elements*, so you need to work with `scale` functions. 
Try `scale_fill_brewer`, e.g.:

```
 scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

For details on this function see [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_brewer.html).

Comment: Not what he wants I think. This doesn't work for instance:theme_new <-  geom_bar(fill="white")

ggplot(iris)+ geom_bar(aes(Sepal.Length)) +    theme_new

Comment: No, I'd like to set the default colour in the theme as JT85 mentioned

Comment: I see, no problem, will keep answer while thinking about it.

Comment: changed to use scale_fill_brewer