# ggplot2: Setting default colour/fill for geom_bin()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to set the default fill-colour for geom_bin(). I thought

```
update_stat_defaults("bin", list(colour="red", fill="green"))
```

should set the fill-colour to green and the boundary to red (such as

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x)) + stat_bin(color="red", fill="green")
```

does).

But

```
update_stat_defaults("bin", list(colour="red", fill="green"))
ggplot(data, aes(x=x)) + stat_bin()
```

gives me black bars. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In [ggplot2: How do I set the default fill-colour of geom_bar() in a theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150303/ggplot2-how-do-i-set-the-default-fill-colour-of-geom-bar-in-a-theme) I found the answer

```
update_geom_defaults("bar",   list(fill = "green", colour="red"))
```