# ggplot2: default fill if aesthetic not supplied

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyeval

I've got a function that uses ggplot. I'd like to either pass it a variable to use for the `fill` aesthetic, or use a different colour when I don't pass in anything.

The if/else statement does that for the function below, but my actual function is a bit more complicated and has a few if/else branches, so I'd like to minimise them.

Would it be possible to set the default fill for `geom_bar()` to `"blue"`, but have that overridden if I pass in a `fill` aesthetic?

Alternatively, I was thinking of creating a list of arguments to be passed to `geom_bar()`, based on the arguments passed to my function, and splicing it in using `!!!`. I haven't really got my head around tidyeval/quasiquotation yet though so I don't quite know how that would work.

I'm open to other solutions too though.

```
library(ggplot2)

plotter <- function(x = mtcars, fill = NULL) {
    p <- ggplot(x, aes(factor(cyl)))

    # I don't like this if/else statement
    if (!is.null(fill)) { 
        p <- p + geom_bar(mapping = aes_string(group = fill, fill = fill))
    } else {
        p <- p + geom_bar(fill = "blue")
    }

    p
}

plotter()
plotter(fill = "as.factor(gear)")
```

Comment: See `update_geom_defaults()` for setting the defaults of a geom.  Sounds like it might be what you are after.

Comment: If that's what you needed, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150303/ggplot2-how-do-i-set-the-default-fill-colour-of-geom-bar-in-a-theme) may be a duplicate.

Comment: I think that'd do the trick, but I don't love the idea of updating defaults in my function. I'd have to reset them at the end, and if the function fails halfway through I'd be left with strange defaults.

Comment: if you reset geom default in on.exit, it will be reset even if your function fails halfway through.